# ‘meta’ in Meta title is a serif font

Tags: bug, design

The word ‘meta’ in the .meta-title is a serif font instead of sans-serif. The font family was previously sans-serif, but is now using the default font for the browser, which in Safari is Times.

[image: .meta-title]

Comment: It is sans for me. Is this already fixed?

Comment: @Lang What's your browser? I can still repro this in Safari (& TP) and Chrome, and briefly inspecting the CSS shows no appropriate font family being assigned which could make it sans. Do you have a custom style sheet in your browser?

Comment: Seeing it with Safari Version 11.1 (12605.1.33.1.2), Stylish: no custom CSS for this site. Recheck in Firefox: sans.

Comment: @Lang I've just downloaded and installed Firefox for the first time and it's serif for me, how odd!

Comment: For fun I rechecked in all browsers. Vivaldi, Opera, iCab, Qupzilla, Omniweb…: sans. Then I did it on Windows with FF & Edge: serif! (But not Times, but Constantia?) Seems strange. I have serif fonts active and available for browsers, they all differ regarding use of addons, plugins, proxies, engines. Yet, seems to be on my end. Somehow.

Comment: New user: sans also in all browsers so far. But *Opera 12.16:* serif on the same machine. OS is Sierra.